# Suppose $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers, $0<a<b$, and $d>0$. Prove that if $ac\geq bd$ then $c>d$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Prove that if $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers and $0 < a < b$ and $d > 0$ and $ac ≥ bd$ then $c > d$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297108/prove-that-if-a-b-c-and-d-are-real-numbers-and-0-a-b-and-d-0)

This is exercise $3.1.11$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $(2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are real numbers, $0<a<b$, and $d>0$. Prove that if $ac\geq bd$ then $c>d$.

The solution to this problem is available in appendix $1$, but I was wondering about another possible solution:

*Proof.* We will prove the contrapositive. Suppose $c\leq d$. Since $0<a<b$, then multiplying $a$ by $c$ and $b$ by $d$ will preserve the direction of the inequality and so $ac<bd$ as required. Therefore if $ac\geq bd$ then $c>d$. $Q.E.D.$

Is the above proof valid?

Comment: " then multiplying a by c and b by d will preserve the direction of the inequality"  For a student of a class this basic I'd like to see this broken into steps:  $ac < bc$ and $bc \le bd$ so $ac < bd$..... But, yes.  The proof is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not happy with "then multiplying a by c and b by d will preserve the direction of the inequality".  I'm not sure that's clear and I'm not sure you can claim that without justification.

You *could* prove that as a lemma.

Lemma: If $m < n$ and $0 < u \le v$ the $mu < nv$.

Pf: $mu < nu$ and $nu \le nv$ (as well as $mu \le mv$ and $mv <  nv$ ) so by transitivity $mu < nv$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really the answer that I needed. I am new to proofs and so I was not sure about how much justification do I need.

Comment: Like I said... I'm not happy with it... that doesn't mean it's not acceptable. It'd depend on what propositions you have and haven't proven in class so far.

Comment: I am actually self-studying the material. I am at the beginning of the proof-writing chapter (chapter 3 - section 2) of the aforementioned book.

Answer (score 0):

If $c \le d \implies ac \le ad < bd \implies ac < bd$, contradiction. Thus $c > d$.

Comment: I know about other proofs, I just wanted to know about the validity of the above proof.